# How to refer a solve answer to NDsolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages

I don't know how to refer a solution of Solve to compute it in NDSolve, here's my code

```
acu = FullSimplify[D[\[Rho] \[Pi] (5 a^2 - a^3/3), a]]/.a->a[t];
ode = Solve[acu/(\[Pi] \[Rho]) a'[t] == -0.01123 Sqrt[a[t]], a'[t]]
Sol = NDSolve[{(a'[t] /. ode[[1]]) == a'[t], a[0] == 3}, a, {t, 0, 180}]
```

In the third line I tried to refer the solution and set it equal to a'[t], but in the solve line it was already a'[t]==the solution I want

thanks for all the help

Comment: You need to use `a[t]` instead of `a` in the definition of `acu`.

Comment: yeah, i just corrected that with  /.a->a[t]

Comment: thanks, or that's the solution?

Comment: Edit your question to explain why you are not yet getting the answer you expect even after applying Carl's suggestion.

Comment: I just discovered that was the mistake, should I erase the question? Thanks a lot @CarlWoll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your update to the OP, the error message you got was `NDSolve::dvnoarg`:

```
Sol=NDSolve[{(a'[t]/.ode[[1]])==a'[t],a[0]==3},a,{t,0,180}]
```

> NDSolve::dvnoarg: The function a appears with no arguments.

> NDSolve[{(0.01123 Sqrt[a[t]])/((-10. + a) a) == Derivative[1][a][t],
> a[0] == 3}, a, {t, 0, 180}]

Notice that the [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) equations contain both `a` and `a[t]`. The message is telling you that `a` occurs with no arguments. Every instance of `a` must have an argument, so you need to replace `a` with `a[t]` as you do in the update to your OP.